# How to make my browser (such as Firefox) open a custom File Manager?

Tags: firefox, explorer, regedit

My system is Windows 11 build 22621. Now I use Tablacus Explorer to manage my files instead of Explorer.exe, however, many apps (such as Firefox or Control Panel) will still use Explorer.exe when I try to open directory or other something in those apps，even though I used some Tablacus's plugins such as Shell Execute Hook.
Are there better methods to let other apps to auto open Tablacus as more as possible？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "Open Instead" and "System Tray" plugin to solve the problem.

Comment: You could be a bit more explicit, and add that "Open Instead" and "System Tray" are Tablacus plugins.